# Direct Connect a server to 2 clients using 10 GBE Cooper

Tags: 10gbethernet

I want to direct connect my server to two clients using 10 GBE.

I plan to use the ATTO FastFrame NT12 NIC.

http://www.attotech.com/products/product.php?cat=14&scat=34&prod=111&sku=FFRM-NT12-000

Now, few question as i'm new to the 10GBE:

1. can i assign a static IP C class address to each port on the card that is on the server (total of 2 ports=2 IP address)?
2. Can i assign a static IP address to the client and to let the server and the client communicate between them on a standard subnet? for example:
   The server address will be 192.168.1.1 and the client address will be 192.168.1.2 with a subnet of 255.255.255.0?
3. after a connection will be established between the server and the server, will i be able to map a shared folder on the client (from the server) as i was mapping under 1GB network?
4. For direct connection betwen server and client - i know i need to use CAT 6a or CAT 7 cable - BUT, do i need a standard cable or a crossover cable?

Thanks

Dori

Comment: Transferring files will be as easy as you want to make it, are these Windows systems? You'd share a directory, assign permissions and either make or let Windows automatically make firewall exceptions for you, I like to add another sharing mechanism such as FTP / HTTP in case for any reason I can't predict Windows NetBIOS file sharing fails and I have to maintain uptime and functionality. Most versions of windows include Intenret Information Services or the 10 connection version Personal Web Svcs in their workstation versions.,

Comment: Yes to 1 and 2, regarding #3, the size of the bandwidth won't affect the ability to set permissions to file shares.

Comment: Ok. Thanks! How can i know for sure that i can use standard cables and there is no need for crossover cables ?what should i search in the spec of the NIC's?

Comment: Beyond just confirming it with the reseller, I don't know since I read the description and it didn't stipulate it specifically. it is a reasonable assumption contemporary network cards include auto detect the way it is reasonable to assume all cars include a glove box.  And the you're buying ferarris so I'd be damn surprised but just buy a X-over if you have to be 100%

Comment: well, at this point I think I've earned the Answer credit and deserve as much, I can't do a better job of explaining the auto detect than Wikipedia because I would just unintenationally seem patronizing.
My earlier metaphor about cars with gloveboxes,  you don't find the glovebox listed as a line item or at the web sites description because it is a reasonable assumption. Even professional grade cisco devices that used to require skill and a bag of xovers by LAN managers will auto detect and its no longer a requirement for years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes to 1 and 2, regarding #3, the size of the bandwidth won't affect the ability to set permissions to file shares. 
Transferring files will be as easy as you want to make it, are these Windows systems? You'd share a directory, assign permissions and either make or let Windows automatically make firewall exceptions for you, I like to add another sharing mechanism such as FTP / HTTP in case for any reason I can't predict Windows NetBIOS file sharing fails and I have to maintain uptime and functionality. Most versions of windows include Intenret Information Services or the 10 connection version Personal Web Svcs in their workstation versions.

Traditionally you'd need a cross over but modern NIC's I've used for years and especially yours will autodetect and reverse their polarity for connectivity and usually without user interaction and menu acknoweldgements.

Can I come over and use your network ? You got bandwidth to burn and you're gonna transfer large files faster than a ferret farts.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-MDIX#Auto-MDIX